を　と? Is it similar some kind of grammar?

それを手段の一つとして戦える敵か。厄介だ…

The character is fighting an enemy who has the special ability to teleport. So he says this
Is を　として here some kind of grammar? "An enemy who can fight that way"?

But what is の一つ here then?

"An enemy who can fight using it as one of the means".
